# How do I check two nodes indirect connection

Tags: python

What is the best way to check if two nodes are indirectly connected?

Let's take for example the **RGB** node and the **Hue/Saturation/Value** nodes. They are not directly, but connected, with other nodes between them.

Is there a better way than looping through the linked nodes starting with the **RGB** node's "Color" output?
[image]

Comment: the node tree is a tree, so there is probably no other option than to [traverse the tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) recursively.

Comment: FWIW when you press "L" when hovering over a node it will select all connected nodes. I bet under the hood it traverses the tree but you might only need to execute this specific operator in your script and see if the other node is selected afterwards

Comment: @Gorgious I've just tried the L key in the Shader Editor. It calls bpy.ops.node.select_linked_from(). But this selects nothing if the node is not selected and I just hover it. If I select it first then L selects the next on the left side. Another press of key L selects the next one on the left side and so on.

Comment: bpy.ops.node.select_linked_from() would be great if the selected node and the selection length could be given as parameters and the connected nodes would be returned. Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything about this yet.

Comment: I think what you want can be done in a 15 line script or so, what exactly poses you a problem with this solution ?

Comment: Nothing, just asking if there is something that I don't know of